# Auto stop SQL Server service while logging off a specific user

Tags: sql-server, windows, authentication, windows-services

I can use the below commands to start and stop SQL services.
`net start SQL_SERVICE_NAME` and `net stop SQL_SERVICE_NAME`.

Now, how can I start the service while the user `UserA` login to the computer and stop the service while the user log off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Task Scheduler from Control Panel>Administrative Tools.

Put your *net start* and *net stop* commands in their own separate `.bat` files and save somewhere suitable.

In Task Scheduler, create two new tasks, one for starting, one for stopping. On the `Action` tab you add the relevant .bat file to run. On the `Triggers` tab you can choose to *Begin the task* on connection and disconnection (as appropriate) of a specific user.

Comment: Oh... Great, so simple.